# simple platform game in Android

Tags: android, animation

I am looking to create a very simple Android platform game. For this, I am going to use the Capcom character "Ryu". I have a set of images that I have used, to animate as a frame animation. Ulimately it will depend on key presses or touch events. As of now I am simply running a sequence of the whole set of images.

As a first run, I had the background of all the images set to black. However, I would like to add some on my own backgrounds for the character. How can I do this?
(Am using Android 1.5)

Thanks,
Angelo.

Comment: Try looking/asking here instead http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it sounds like you need to make versions of your sprite imagery with a transparent background, so you can draw them on your scene, or create canned frames with them.  For this, you need to use a program like GIMP (or Photoshop).  See, for instance, this: http://www.fabiovisentin.com/tutorial/GIMP_transparent_image/gimp_how_to_make_transparent_image.asp

George

P.S. Also, when doing animation, you will need to be very careful about your memory usage.  See, for instance, this: http://davidjhinson.wordpress.com/2010/05/19/scarce-commodities-google-android-memory-and-bitmaps/